# [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function when upgrade to vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

After upgrade my project to vue 3.x, I recieved this warning information in the console output.

```
commons1.js:7039 [Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <StBox ref="st" > 
  at <App>
```

this is my template.html file looks like:

```
<section class="text-center functions">
  <div v-if="canInject">
    <div role="button" @click="switchEnable" :title="'点击切换为'+(enabled?'禁':'启')+'用状态'">已对当前网站<span v-if="enabled">启用</span><span v-else>禁用</span></div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    划词翻译没有权限操作当前网页
  </div>
  <st-box ref="st"></st-box>
</section>
```

seems the vue 3 treated the lable st-box as a component but I could not found the StBox component in the whole project. where is going wrong? what should I do to fix this warning message? I am import the ST component like this:

```
import ST from './st';
```

and define the component in app.js in component like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import template from './tpl.html';
import chromeCall from 'chrome-call';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {getTabLocation,isHostEnabled} from '../public/util';
import ST from './st';
import { createApp } from "vue";

    export const appOptions = {
      el : 'app' ,
      template ,
      setup () {
        const host =null;
        const canInject =false;
        const enabled = false;
        return {host,canInject,enabled};
      } ,
      methods : {
        async switchEnable() {
          const {host} = this.$data ,
            enabled = this.enabled = !this.enabled ,
            {excludeDomains} = await getOptions( 'excludeDomains' );
    
          if ( enabled ) {
            excludeDomains.splice( excludeDomains.indexOf( host ) , 1 );
          } else {
            excludeDomains.push( _host );
          }
          return chromeCall( 'storage.local.set' , { excludeDomains } );
        }
      } ,
      components : {
        'st-box' : ST
      } ,
      async ready() {
        const locationObj = await getTabLocation();
        if ( locationObj ) {
          this.$data.host = locationObj.host;
          this.canInject = true;
          this.enabled = await isHostEnabled( locationObj );
        }
      }
    };
    
    if ( process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'testing' ) {
      window.onload = ()=> {
        setTimeout( ()=> {
          const app = createApp(appOptions);
          app.mount("app");
        }, 0 );
      };
    }
```

this is the `st.js` define:

```
import client from './client';
import getOptions from '../public/default-options';
import {read} from '../public/clipboard';
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent( { 
  client ,
  async compiled() {
    this.inline = true;
    this.showForm = true;
    const {defaultApi , autoClipboard} = await getOptions( [ 'defaultApi' , 'autoClipboard' ] );

    this.query.api = defaultApi;
    if ( autoClipboard ) {
      this.query.text = read();
      this.safeTranslate();
    }
  } ,
  ready() {
    setTimeout( ()=> this.$els.textarea.focus() , 200 );
  }
} );
```

Comment: How do you import StBox component ?

Comment: I pasted the code to show how to import the ST component in the code snippnet. @AdriHM

Comment: I think you have to put all the methods that are in `defineComponent` of st.js in the setup function and return those functions